# Applying graduated renderer in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, symbology

Just trying to run the following code already given in the pyqgis cookbook to create graduated colors symbology (as in example with 2 classes)

I define the source info for the shapefile but when I run execute the code within my test-plugin, it just adds the layer without classifiying. Just adds as usual, all polylines appear same.

Any solution or working code/method?

link to code in cookbook
http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#graduated-symbol-renderer

```
from qgis.core import  (QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2, QgsSymbolV2,QgsRendererRangeV2)

myVectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/my_test_shape_file.shp', 'test_shp_file', 'ogr')

myTargetField = 'target_field'
myRangeList = []
myOpacity = 1

# Make our first symbol and range...
myMin = 0.0
myMax = 50.0
myLabel = 'Group 1'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#ffee00')
mySymbol1 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol1.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol1.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange1 = QgsRendererRangeV2(myMin, myMax, mySymbol1, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange1)

#now make another symbol and range...
myMin = 50.1
myMax = 100
myLabel = 'Group 2'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#00eeff')
mySymbol2 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol2.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol2.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange2 = QgsRendererRangeV2( myMin, myMax, mySymbol2, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange2)

myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2('', myRangeList)
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.EqualInterval)
myRenderer.setClassAttribute(myTargetField)
myVectorLayer.setRendererV2(myRenderer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(myVectorLayer)
```

---

@Kelly's code works perfectly.

However I noticed that both the code (one I have typed in my first message and yours in the 2nd message) DO NOT work in QGIS v1.7.3 but WORKS in QGIS v1.8.0. I think this was a bug(?) that already resolved in v1.8.0

And one more question;

Do you have any sample code for (natural breaks, Jenks) classification of the "numeric_attribute_field" based on given number of classes (i.e. no of classes will be a variable in the code, say "n", and I will pass that from the plugin GUI i.e. n = spinBox.value() )

Comment: Please read the help on how to format the code for this site.  I have fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 20):

I found that with the point layer I was using the following line returned `None`

```
mySymbol1 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
```

However this could be fixed by replacing it with a call to the `validatedDefaultSymbol` method from the code below.  The basic premise is to call `QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol()` and then to validate and if needed make corrections .

---

Changes to ensure compatibility with both QGIS 1.8 and current master (27/01/13); extended to a series of examples with wider scope.*

The snippets below are formatted to be pasted into the python console and to be applied to Natural Earth Data 1:10m Populated Places available from [here](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/). Note that the later snippets have dependencies on definitions and imports from the first one.

1) This is an example of applying custom but hard coded categories to a given layer.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def validatedDefaultSymbol( geometryType ):
    symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol( geometryType )
    if symbol is None:
        if geometryType == QGis.Point:
            symbol = QgsMarkerSymbolV2()
        elif geometryType == QGis.Line:
            symbol =  QgsLineSymbolV2 ()
        elif geometryType == QGis.Polygon:
            symbol = QgsFillSymbolV2 ()
    return symbol

def makeSymbologyForRange( layer, min , max, title, color):
    symbol = validatedDefaultSymbol( layer.geometryType() )
    symbol.setColor( color )
    range = QgsRendererRangeV2( min, max, symbol, title )
    return range

def applySymbologyFixedDivisions( layer, field ):
    rangeList = []
    rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange( layer, -99, 999999.9, '<1 Million', QColor("Green") ) )
    rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange( layer, 1000000, 10000000, '1-10 Million',  QColor("Purple") ) )
    rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange( layer, 10000000.1, 100000000, '>10 Million', QColor("Orange") ) )
    renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2( field, rangeList )
    renderer.setMode( QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.Custom )
    layer.setRendererV2( renderer )

targetField = 'POP_OTHER'
layer = QgsVectorLayer( 'C:/data/ne_10m_populated_places.shp', 'Fixed Divisions', 'ogr' )
if layer.isValid():
    applySymbologyFixedDivisions( layer, targetField )
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers( [layer] )
```

2) This example applies, in turn, each of the standard modes supported by QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.  The classes value will be treated as a hint rather than a rule as required by each specific mode. The setSizeScaleField line can be uncommented if desired, however the values of the LABELRANK column too large to look good at standard zoom levels.

```
def applyGraduatedSymbologyStandardMode( layer, field, classes, mode):
    symbol = validatedDefaultSymbol( layer.geometryType() )
    colorRamp = QgsVectorGradientColorRampV2.create({'color1':'255,0,0,255', 'color2':'0,0,255,255','stops':'0.25;255,255,0,255:0.50;0,255,0,255:0.75;0,255,255,255'})
    renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.createRenderer( layer, field, classes, mode, symbol, colorRamp )
    #renderer.setSizeScaleField("LABELRANK")
    layer.setRendererV2( renderer )

modes = { QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.EqualInterval : "Equal Interval",
          QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.Quantile      : "Quantile",
          QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.Jenks         : "Natural Breaks (Jenks)",
          QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.StdDev        : "Standard Deviation",
          QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.Pretty        : "Pretty Breaks"
        }

targetField = 'POP_OTHER'
classes = 6
for mode in modes.keys():
    layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/data/ne_10m_populated_places.shp', modes[mode] , 'ogr')
    if layer.isValid():
        applyGraduatedSymbologyStandardMode( layer, targetField, classes, mode)
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers( [layer] )
```

3) This example demonstrates applying dynamic custom divisions.  In this case the features are sorted by value, then split into groups such that the sum of the values in each category are equal.  i.e. split the worlds population into thirds that live in places of the smallest / medium / largest population.

```
def getSortedFloatsFromAttributeTable( layer, fieldName ):
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    fieldIndex = provider.fieldNameIndex(fieldName)
    provider.select( [fieldIndex] )
    values = []
    feature = QgsFeature()
    while provider.nextFeature( feature ):
        values.append( feature.attributeMap()[fieldIndex].toFloat()[0] )
    values.sort()
    return values

def arbitaryColor( amount, max ):
    color = QColor()
    color.setHsv( 240 * amount / float( max - 1 ), 255, 255 )
    return color

def makeGraduatedRendererFromDivisionsList( layer, fieldName, divisions ):
    classes = len( divisions ) - 1
    rangeList = []
    for i in range( classes ):
        label = str( divisions[i] ) + " < X < " + str( divisions[i+1] )
        rangeList.append( makeSymbologyForRange( layer, divisions[i] , divisions[i+1], label, arbitaryColor( i, classes ) ) )
    renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2( fieldName, rangeList )
    renderer.setMode( QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.Custom )
    return renderer

def applySymbologyEqualTotalValue( layer, classes, fieldName):
    values = getSortedFloatsFromAttributeTable( layer, fieldName )
    total = sum( values )
    step = total / float( classes )
    nextStep = step
    divisions = [ values[0] ]
    runningTotal = 0
    for value in values:
        runningTotal += value
        if runningTotal >= nextStep:
            divisions.append( value )
            nextStep += step
    if divisions[-1] != values[-1]:
        divisions.append(values[-1])
    renderer = makeGraduatedRendererFromDivisionsList( layer, fieldName, divisions )
    layer.setRendererV2( renderer )

targetField = 'POP_OTHER'
classes = 3
layer = QgsVectorLayer( 'C:/data/ne_10m_populated_places.shp', 'Equal Total Value', 'ogr')
if layer.isValid():
    applySymbologyEqualTotalValue(layer, classes, targetField)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers( [layer] )
```

Comment: I'd like to say a couple things. First, if you are trying to re-create the above answer from @Kelly, make sure to choose the "download populated places" file from Kelly's link.

If you'd like to see an updated version of this code for PyQGIS 3 / QGIS 3.x, see this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303990/applying-graduated-renderer-to-polygon-using-pyqgis-3/304303#304303
I am using a different shapefile, keep in mind. But the code is very similar and you should be able to follow it. A few methods and things have changed for QGIS 3.