# How to remove a layer and its legend in a standalone pyqgis application?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, legend, standalone

In continuity in my question [How to add a legend to a canvas in a standalone PyQGIS application?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141516/how-to-add-a-legend-to-a-canvas-in-a-standalone-pyqgis-application) > In every addition of a new layer in my standalone application, the legend lengthens and becomes overloaded. So I would like to know how to remove one or several layers with his(their) legend(s). Sorry for my english.

Comment: I haven't been able to remove layers safely using `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(id)`. I keep getting segmentation faults when removing/adding layers (like here: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/PyQGIS-Problems-with-the-layerWasAdded-SIGNAL-td4118064.html). Could you confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

your question isn't a QGIS question, but a QT question. Legend tree is managed by [QgsLegendTreeView](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/01/30/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-3/) that is a QTreeView. So all what you need is to browse you tree an hide rows to compact your legend with http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#setRowHidden
If you simply want to remove a layer from QGIS (standalone or not) simply unregister it from QgsMapLayerRegistry with QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(layerId)