# pyscripter : add a legend to my vector layer

Tags: pyqgis, pyscripter

I work on PyScripter, i managed to display a vector layer from Postgresql with a symbology.
But I have a difficulty to display a legend.

```
def main():
```

def init():

# appel de l'application et initialisation
   a = QgsApplication(sys.argv, True)
   QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis", True)
   QgsApplication.initQgis()
   return a

def show_shape(app):

```
# definition a connection
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "stat", "postgres", "admin")
uri.setDataSource("public", "com", "the_geom", ' ', "gid")
uri.uri()

# crÃ©ation d'une fenÃªtre et chargement d'une couche
carte = QgsMapCanvas()
layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'com', 'postgres')
if not layer.isValid():
   print "Layer failed to load!"

# add layer to the registry
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
carte.setExtent(layer.extent())

# affichage de la couche dans une fenÃªtre
carte.setLayerSet( [ QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer) ] )
carte.show()

#personnaliser la symbologie
myTargetField = 'code'
myRangeList = []
myOpacity = 1

# Make our first symbol and range...
myMin = 0.0
myMax = 100.0
myLabel = '0.0-200'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('white')#ffee00
mySymbol1 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
mySymbol1.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol1.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange1 = QgsRendererRangeV2(myMin,myMax,mySymbol1,myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange1)

#now make two symbol and range...
myMin = 100.1
myMax = 102
myLabel = '200.1-500'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('yellow')#00eeff
mySymbol2 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
mySymbol2.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol2.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange2 = QgsRendererRangeV2(myMin,myMax,mySymbol2,myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange2)

myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2('', myRangeList)
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.EqualInterval)
myRenderer.setClassAttribute(myTargetField)

layer.setRendererV2(myRenderer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
print "fine"

app.exec_()
```

app = init()
 show_shape(app)

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got you right, but you can add a legend widget to your PyQGIS application following [How to add a legend to a canvas in a standalone PyQGIS application?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141516/how-to-add-a-legend-to-a-canvas-in-a-standalone-pyqgis-application/141578#141578)

Besides displaying your layers' symbology, it allows you to rename layers, set layer visibility, and change layer order in the map canvas.

Comment: I'll try with this example, and I remind you soon

Comment: @Nora27 So, did it work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I did not understand how can I rephrase the code. I tried many