# Render QgsRasterLayer without adding to legend

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to render a number of related QgsRasterLayer objects that are related to eachother (they are slippy-type tiles). Ideally I would like one item in the legend that can have its position changed (i.e. move above or below other legend items) and add custom actions/properties dialog to, but have the actual rendering of the tiles be done by QgsRasterLayer.

My first approach was to attempt to subclass QgsPluginLayer and override the `draw()` method to call `QgsRasterLayer.draw()` for each of my loaded rasters. This does nothing, even if layers are added to the `QgsMapLayerRegistry`.

```
def draw(self, renderContext):
    for rasterlayer in self.loadedlayers.values():
       rasterlayer.draw(renderContext)
```

My second approach was to create a group in the legend that is somehow hidden. I can add the layer to the layer tree using

```
mygroup = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().addGroup("mygroup")
for rasterlayer in self.loadedlayers.values():
    mygroup.addMapLayer(rasterlayer)
```

but it doesn't seem possible to hide this group from the user. From [Showing only some layers in QGIS legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160565/how-to-show-only-some-layers-in-the-qgis-legend) it doesn't seem like there is an alternative. I feel as though there is an easy solution to this that I'm not seeing.

EDIT: I tried creating a `QgsMapLayerRenderer` object that renders the layer to an image using a `QgsMapRenderer`, and while this occasionally works, it often produces output that appears to have elements of the current screen in the output image (maybe having something to do with using a QgsMapRenderer() while one is already invoked on the current thread?). In my `QgsPluginLayer` I have:

```
def createMapRenderer(self, context):
    return MultiRasterRenderer(self, context)
```

And my `QgsMapLayerRenderer` is this (includes some debugging output):

```
class MultiRasterRenderer(QgsMapLayerRenderer):

    def __init__(self, layer, context):
        QgsMapLayerRenderer.__init__(self, layer.id())
        self.layer = layer
        self.context = context

    def render(self):
        fout = open("/Users/dewey/Desktop/outputdump.txt", "w")
        rendererContext = self.context
        if len(self.layer.loadedlayers) > 0:
            img = QImage(QSize(self.context.painter().device().width(),
                                    self.context.painter().device().height()),
                              QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
            painter = QPainter()
            painter.begin(img)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

            render = QgsMapRenderer()
            render.setLayerSet([layer.id() for layer in self.layer.loadedlayers.values()])
            render.setProjectionsEnabled(True)
            render.setDestinationCrs(rendererContext.coordinateTransform().destCRS())


            fout.write("Context extent: " + rendererContext.extent().toString() + "\n")


            if render.setExtent(rendererContext.extent()):
                render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
                render.render(painter)
                painter.end()

                img.save("/Users/dewey/Desktop/output.jpg")

                rendererContext.painter().drawImage(0, 0, img)

                fout.write("Render extent: " + render.extent().toString() + "\n")
            else:
                fout.write("render.setExtent() returned false\n")
        else:
            fout.write("No tiles to load, skipping rendering")

        fout.close()
        return True
```

Comment: Maybe a VRT virtual raster works for you. Raster layers are grouped and will be visualized and processed together.

Comment: I considered this, but the documentation is poor and because many tiled image datasets are .png images, they are pallleted and not RGB, which complicates writing a VRT XML file. Even if this is the case, I still have to render it without it showing up in the legend, which seems impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much debugging, I finally found a somewhat simple solution. When creating a new `QImage()` it seems, the `QImage()` is not blank, and thus the solution to this problem was to call `QImage.fill(Qt.transparent)` before rendering the map to the image. It was unnecessary to invoke a `QgsMapLayerRenderer` because there was no multi-threaded rendering happening...all was happening from the renderer thread. The final `QgsPluginLayer` code is as follows:

```
class QOSMTileLayer(QgsPluginLayer):

    LAYER_TYPE = "QOSM_LAYER_TYPE"

    def __init__(self, layertype, layerName):
        QgsPluginLayer.__init__(self, QOSMTileLayer.LAYER_TYPE, layerName)
        self.layertype = layertype
        self.loadedtiles = set()
        self.loadedlayers = {}
        self.setValid(True)

    def refrshlayers(self):
        ...

    def draw(self, rendererContext):
        if len(self.loadedlayers) > 0:

            render = QgsMapRenderer()
            render.setLayerSet(self.loadedlayers.values())
            render.setProjectionsEnabled(True)
            render.setDestinationCrs(rendererContext.coordinateTransform().destCRS())
            render.setExtent(rendererContext.extent())

            img = QImage(QSize(rendererContext.painter().device().width(),
                        rendererContext.painter().device().height()),
                  QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
            img.fill(Qt.transparent) #needed, apparently the QImage() is not empty

            painter = QPainter()
            painter.begin(img)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
            render.render(painter)
            painter.end()

            rendererContext.painter().drawImage(0, 0, img)            
        else:
            #no tiles.
            pass

        return True
```