# Making layer or group private/hidden/invisible in Layers Panel of QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, table-of-contents

I have a number of layers in the **Layers Panel** inside a group but I don't want them shown (there's quite a lot so it looks untidy). These layers are also joined to several others.

Is it possible to make these layers **invisible** to the user (**i.e. not shown in the Layers Panel, it is not about setting the visibility of the layer**) but can still be joined to other layers, or perhaps to make the group invisible?

Closest I found was this post but hoping there's a more direct approach:

[Showing only some layers in QGIS legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160565/showing-only-some-layers-in-qgis-legend)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Just to clarify, private/hidden layers/groups will not appear in the Layers Panel, but they can still be seen in the canvas or used in joins/relations with other layers.*

### Native approach (QGIS API)

You need at least QGIS v3.18.

Using the native approach, you can **make a layer 'Private'** (or hidden) in this way:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setFlags(QgsMapLayer.Private)
```

See [Making layer private/hidden/invisible in QGIS Layers Panel without Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/401829/4972) to do this using the QGIS GUI.

However, **using the native approach there is no way of making a layer group Private** (or hidden). For that you would need the Plugin approach.

### Plugin approach

You need at least QGIS v3.4.

I find making layers/groups hidden/invisible useful to avoid showing lookup tables, which are required for value relations but might make the Layers Panel look a bit overloaded.

---

ANSWER:

Use the plugin [Invisible layers and groups](https://github.com/gacarrillor/InvisibleLayersAndGroups), which allows you to:

- Make selected layers/groups hidden/invisible (plugin button).
- Make layers/groups (that are hidden/invisible) visible again (plugin button).
- Store layers/groups visibility in your QGIS project.
- Recreate layers/groups visibility when opening your QGIS project.
- Make a particular layer hidden/invisible (by code).
- Make a particular group hidden/invisible (by code).

Making a layer hidden/invisible (by code):

```
if 'InvisibleLayersAndGroups' in qgis.utils.plugins:
    ilg = qgis.utils.plugins['InvisibleLayersAndGroups']
    ilg.hideLayer( layer )    # layer is a QgsMapLayer
```

Making a group hidden/invisible (by code):

```
if 'InvisibleLayersAndGroups' in qgis.utils.plugins:
    ilg = qgis.utils.plugins['InvisibleLayersAndGroups']
    ilg.hideGroup( group )    # group is a QgsLayerTreeGroup
    ilg.hideGroup( 'group2' ) # You can also pass a group name
```

---

*Note: Depending on your use case, stick to one approach: either native or plugin, but don't use both at the same time.*