# How to remove layer from layers panel, but keep in memory

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers

Is it possible to remove a layer from the layers panel and the map canvas without removing it from memory. e.g if i have a vector layer named vlayer, and add it to the map with QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer), and then later remove it from the map, but still want to operate on vlayer. 
I have tryed QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(vlayer.id()), but then it seems that the layer is removed from vlayer as well

Comment: I asked a somewhat [related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229826/how-to-make-a-layer-or-group-invisible-in-the-layers-panel) where it is possible to make the selected layer _invisible_ (i.e. it is removed from canvas but can still be accessed).

Comment: @Joseph Thank you, that was usefull. By combining it with iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(vlayer, False) I was able to achive what i wanted