# Making layer private/hidden/invisible in QGIS Layers Panel without Python

Tags: qgis, relationship-class, layertree

I have postgresql/postgis database setup with one to many relationship. I can successfully set it up in QGIS but **I would like to keep related tables hidden from Layers Panel** to keep the project "clean" since later on I might be adding more complex databases, value map tables etc..

For example, I have locations layer where each point can relate to several events in events layer. I would like to edit data in form like this so each location can be updated with new events only that **events table would not be visible in Layers Panel**:

[image]

Is there some way to achieve this without going into PyQGIS?

I am just starting with PyQGIS.

Comment: not 100% sure what you mean but I'm almost certain PostgreSQL [*Views*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createview.html) (or [*Materialized Views*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-creatematerializedview.html)) are what you want *if* you are working with in-DB joins only.

Comment: Thanks for response, I Updated the question to make it clear what i want to achieve. Views, if i understand right, allow me to create joined tables and would multipy "locations" to match number of unique "events"/"location" combinations from my example and not allow me to use emebeded attribute tables in forms?

Comment: Why not create an updatable view in PostgreSQL ?
More informations in the PG documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html,  `Updatable Views` section.

Comment: Natively I don't see any way of hiding a layer in the TOC without some pyqgis. In the past I have all the lists stored away in a TOC group. A Virtual Layer can embed a table so it is not visibly in the TOC, but you can not use them in a value map relation.

Answer (score 4):

You need QGIS v3.18 or higher.

Go to `Project` --> `Properties...` --> `Data Sources` and check the layers you want to hide from the Layers Panel (column `Private`).

[image]

If you want to see Private (hidden) layers again, you could revert the aforementioned action (i.e., uncheck the layer in the `Properties` dialog) or do this:

[image]

---

*Note: You can make both spatial and non spatial layers 'Private'.*

Comment: Is there a way to this dynamically rather than having to select the layers you want private? In the TOC can you just hide layers that are not turned on?