# Using PostGIS relationships (M:N) in QGIS without loading all related tables in layertree

Tags: qgis, postgis, relationship-class

I am working with a PostgreSQL/PostGIS (version 12.3/3.0.1) database and I am using QGIS (version 3.10) to visualize and work with my data. In the database I have two schemas:

1. schema for spatial data tables, e. g. gebaeude
2. schema for documents, e. g. dokument, dok_gebaeude (without spatial information)

I set a m:n relation between gebaeude and dokument using the table dok_gebaeude.

My tables are:

1. ***dokument***: id, bezeichnung, dateityp, pfad
2. ***dok_gebaeude***: id, fk_dokument, fk_gebaeude --> fk_dokument references dokument(id) and fk_gebaeude references gebaeude(id)
3. ***gebaeude***: id, geom, nummer, nutzung

In QGIS I loaded the relationship with the *project properties>relation manager* and I can use it to connect documents (stored in table *dokument*) with *gebaeude*-objects. All work fine. BUT...

In QGIS I only need the table gebaeude and I don´t want to load the tables *dokument* and *dok_gebaeude* in my layers (the latter are only technical tables). Unfortunately it is neccessary to load all three tables (*dokument*, *gebaeude* and *dok_gebaeude*) in my layers in QGIS, otherwise I am not able to add the relationship in my *project properties>relations*.

**Is there any possibility to hide or remove or not even load tables (*dokument* and *dok_gebaeude*) in my layertree without losing the relationsships?**

Comment: You probably want to work with PostgreSQL *Views*.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to focus on a single issue.

Comment: You can use the plugin https://github.com/opengisch/QgisModelBaker to setup QGIS project with relations

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Have a look at [How to make a layer or group invisible in the Layers Panel?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230804/4972)

Comment: Thank you @Germán Carrillo - that helps me!