# Use OpenCV in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, opencv

I developing QGIS module and I have a question, how to capture QgsMapCanvas window with OpenCV for shoving in different frame or different application?

Part of the code:

```
class MainWindow( QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow ):
    def __init__( self ):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__( self )
        self.setupUi( self )

        self.setWindowTitle( "QGIS Demo" )

        # Create map ()
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor( QtGui.QColor( 200, 200, 255 ) )
        self.canvas.enableAntiAliasing( True )
        self.canvas.show()
```

Comment: What does this code do in relation to the question?

Comment: This part of code response for showing map window

Comment: Can you add what OpenCV needs in the input? We may know how QGIS works, so we can't help you more about OpenCV. Does a picture work? https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a70bdf0387ea56e87d643b6a36c1e8610 because you have your QgsMapCanvas.

Comment: OpenCV will have data from map view window, in my case raster data for interactive processing and show processed picture in other frame. As pattern i use  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141516/adding-legend-to-canvas-in-standalone-pyqgis-application