# How to create multiple graduated layers using different attributes/columns?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, vector-layer, duplication

I have a shapefile for which I'd like to create multiple graduated layers for each attribute/column. At present, I manually duplicate the layer and then change the column from the drop down list, select a color ramp and update the classes. As I have numerous layers to create, how do I go about automating these steps? Can I do this using a python script?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/48719/163383) can be used to automate all these steps by iterating through a list of columns that layers are required for.